# Creating and destroying bluetooth sockets

Tags: c#, android, sockets, bluetooth, xamarin

I am currently trying to write an app for android with Xamarin where I want to create and destroy sockets to the same device, and then redo that process over again. I have written both client and server code. I am having a problem doing that, since the app always crashes on the server side when it tries to read data from the client for a second time.

What I mean is that it is always successful the first time around, but the second time around, it always crashes. We figured out that the problem was on the client though cause once we started keeping the sockets open and reusing them instead of closing them and recreating a new one when needed, it worked as intended and did not crash. Here is the code we ended up using:

[SERVER]

```
public class BluetoothSocketListener {

    private BluetoothScanner _scanner;
    private BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
    private string TAG = "Socket Listener: ";
    private Thread listenThread;

    public BluetoothSocketListener(BluetoothScanner scanner, UUID uuid) {
        _scanner = scanner;
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        try {
            tmp = scanner.Adapter.ListenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("AGHApp", uuid);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Listen failed, exception: " + e);
        }

        serverSocket = tmp;
        listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListening));
        listenThread.Start();
    }

    private void StartListening() {
        Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Listening...");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while(_scanner.Running){
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.Accept();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Accept failed: " + e);
                break;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                lock (this) {
                    ReadData(socket.InputStream);
                    socket.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        serverSocket.Close();
    }

    private void ReadData(Stream stream) {

        // Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable. 
        if(stream.CanRead){
            byte[] streamData = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder completeMsg = new StringBuilder();
            int bytesRead = 0;

            // Incoming message may be larger or smaller than the buffer size. 
            do{

                bytesRead = stream.Read(streamData, 0, 1);
                completeMsg.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(streamData, 0, bytesRead));
            }
            while(stream.IsDataAvailable());

            // Print out the received message to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Message : " + completeMsg);
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot read from stream");
        }
    }
}
```

[CLIENT]

```
private void SendData(BluetoothDevice device, string msg){

    Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Finding socket");

    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
    if(sockets.ContainsKey(device.Address)) {
        socket = sockets[device.Address];
    }
    else  {
        socket = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_uuid);
        socket.Connect();
        sockets.Add(socket);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Socket connected, writing to socket");

    byte[] bMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    socket.OutputStream.Write(bMsg, 0, bMsg.Length);
    socket.OutputStream.Close();
}
```

As can be seen, I never actually close the sockets on the client side after I send the message. This is not the problem though since if this is necessary, I can easily do this in some other function.

What I would like is to create and close the socket every time I want to send a message, since I only want to send something every 15 minutes, and the device might have moved and is no longer available. It is also not necessary to keep track of the devices. Fire and forget. This is what we started with and would like to have something similar to this as well:

```
private void SendData(BluetoothDevice device, string msg){

    BluetoothSocket socket = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_uuid);
    socket.Connect();


    Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Socket connected, writing to socket");

    byte[] bMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    socket.OutputStream.Write(bMsg, 0, bMsg.Length);
    socket.OutputStream.Close();
    socket.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(TAG + "Socket closed");
}
```

Something to notice is that the server actually closes the socket after it receives the message, why is that even working? And why can't I close the socket on the client side? Am I missing something integral here?

The exception is a Java.IO exception, where the message reads: bt socket closed, read -1

Would really appreciate some help!